# How to get the distance between two geo points in the elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

The following Query in the elasticsearch will give results located within the specified distance. The result doesn't includes the actual distance. Is there any way to get this information in elasticsearch  ?

```
"query": {
    "bool" : {
        "must" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "12km",
                "pin.location" : [-70, 40]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a script field with the same reference point as in the `geo_distance` filter. Full query:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "5000km",
          "pin.location": [
            -70,
            40
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "distance_in_m": {
      "script": "doc['pin.location'].arcDistance(40, -70)"
    }
  }
}
```

OR

[geo-sort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62436400/8160318) and you'll get the distance info included in the sort response.

Comment: Great,  I suppose we can also do this using Java High level REST client right.

Comment: Sure -- dunno how though.