# Return Elasticsearch distance for array of geo points

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless, elasticsearch-scripting

I need to return the distance for **multiple** geo points per document in an Elasticsearch array. As of now, my results only return one distance calculated for the array.

I started with the code from the following StackOverflow question:
[Return distance in elasticsearch results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295118/return-distance-in-elasticsearch-results)

My elasticsearch query body contains this:

```
{
  "stored_fields" : [ "_source" ],
    "script_fields" : {
      "distance" : {
        "script" : {
          "inline": "doc['locations.facility.address.coordinates'].arcDistance(params.lat,params.lon) * 0.001",
          "lang": "painless",
          "params": {
            "lat": 2.27,
            "lon": 50.3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And, my Elasticsearch source documents, when returned, resemble this. *(Note that locations is an array.)*

```
"locations": [
    {
      "facility": {
        "address": {
          "country_code": "US",
          "city": "San Diego",
          "coordinates": {
            "lon": -117.165,
            "lat": 32.8408
          },
          "country_name": "United States",
          "state_province": "California",
          "postal_code": "92123"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "facility": {
        "address": {
          "country_code": "US",
          "city": "Tampa",
          "coordinates": {
            "lon": -82.505,
            "lat": 28.0831
          },
          "country_name": "United States",
          "state_province": "Florida",
          "postal_code": "33613"
        }
      }
    }
```

]

Currently, my results return something similar to this:

```
    "fields": {
      "distance": [
        13952.518249603361
      ]
    }
```

But in the distance array, I need to return a value for **each** entry in 'locations'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one's tricky.

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-api-reference-shared-org-elasticsearch-index-fielddata.html#painless-api-reference-shared-ScriptDocValues-GeoPoints) and the [source code](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/latest/org/elasticsearch/index/fielddata/ScriptDocValues.GeoPoints.html), the `arcDistance` method is only available on the [doc values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html), not on the individual [geo point instances](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.10.2/org/elasticsearch/common/geo/GeoPoint.html) underlying those doc values.

In other words, although we could iterate on `doc['locations.facility.address.coordinates']`, the iteratees don't implement [any geo distance methods](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-api-reference-shared-org-elasticsearch-common-geo.html).

That's a bummer. So we'll have to implement our own geo distance function, perhaps [using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/837957/8160318) the [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula):

```
{
  "stored_fields": [
    "_source"
  ],
  "script_fields": {
    "distance": {
      "script": {
        "inline": """
          float distFrom(float lat1, float lng1, float lat2, float lng2) {
            double earthRadius = 6371000; // meters
            double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
            double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
            double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                       Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
                       Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
            double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
            float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);
            
            return dist;
          }
        
          return params._source.locations.stream().map(location -> {
              def lat = (float) location.facility.address.coordinates.lat;
              def lon = (float) location.facility.address.coordinates.lon;
              return distFrom(lat, lon, (float) params.lat, (float) params.lon) * 0.001;
          }).collect(Collectors.toList())
        """,
        "lang": "painless",
        "params": {
          "lat": 2.27,
          "lon": 50.3
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding

```
"hits" : {
  ...
  "hits" : [
    {
      ...
      "_source" : {
        "locations" : [
          { ... },
          { ... }
        ]
      },
      "fields" : {
        "distance" : [
          15894.470000000001,
          13952.498
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

To be honest, when there's so much scripting effort required, *something's* gone wrong.

Generally speaking, scripts [should be avoided](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html#_avoid_scripts).

But more importantly, when you're not *sorting* by these geo distances, this whole computational effort should be done **outside** of Elasticsearch -- and rather there where you're post-processing the search results. I use [Turf](https://turfjs.org/) for javascript geo calculations, for instance.

Finally, when you store multiple locations/facilities in one array, I'd suggest using [`nested` fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html). They prevent array flattening, plus support [sorting that makes sense](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62436400/8160318).